# Golang, build error inside function

Tags: function, build, compiler-errors, go

So I have a really frustrating build error I have been staring at for the past hour or two.  It involves one of my  functions in my linked list program.  It thinks I have statements outside the function when they are clearly inside, and thinks the { : } ratio is off.  Am I missing something really simple?

```
// Index returns the location of element e. If e is not present,
// return 0 and false; otherwise return the location and true.
func (list *linkedList) Index(e AnyType) (int, bool) {
        var index int = 0
        var contain bool = false
        if list.Contains(e) == false {
            return 0, false
        }
        for int i := 0; i < list.count; i++ {    \\175
            list.setCursor(i)
            if list.cursorPtr.item == e {
                index = list.cursorIdx
                contain = true
            }
        }
        return index, contain    \\182
}    \\183
```

Build errors

```
./lists.go:175: syntax error: unexpected name, expecting {
./lists.go:182: non-declaration statement outside function body
./lists.go:183: syntax error: unexpected }
```

I appreciate any help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's all line 175's fault, should be

```
for i := 0; i < list.count; i++ {
```

note I removed `int`

Comment: Ahh thank you so much!  := declares 'i' as an int already, so that was redundant.  Thanks so much.

Comment: If you do want to declare types explicitly, the type goes *after* the variable in Go: http://play.golang.org/p/HPE35kl7ep